# ajax to return error status code

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a small site where I am doing an ajax call to delete a row from a table. What I'd like to do is to have the php return a status code to trigger the `.success` or `.fail` function in my ajax request.
Looking to different questions I came up with this solution but it is not working:

AJAX call:

```
  function delete_mov(id){
    $.ajax("delete_mov.php?id="+id
    )
    .success(function(){
      bootbox.alert("Movimento "+id+" correttamente cancellato");
    })
    .fail(function(){
      bootbox.alert("Problemi a cancellare il movimento "+id);
    });
  }
```

and php:

```
try{
    $s = $dbh -> prepare("DELETE FROM movimenti_banca WHERE di=$id");
    $s -> execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    http_response_code(500);
    exit;
    //$message = $error_message.' '.$e->getMessage();
}
http_response_code(200);
```

What I cannot get is to trigger the `.fail` when the query is not executed or returns errors. I am sure this query fails because I put an error inside (di instead of id) to be sure of this. 
The `.fail` is triggered if I remove the php file to be called.

**EDIT: modified my code to test it with `http_response_code` but still not triggering the 500 status when the query fails.**

**EDIT2: debugging I realized that even if the query has an error (`di=$id` should be `id=$id`) the catch part is not entered and so the status 500 is never set**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has no idea what your PHP script is supposed to be doing, so it's not looking for a "status" variable in your returned result. All jQuery knows is whether the actual HTTP request "worked". If it gets back a 200 result, ***that's success*** no matter what's ***in*** the result.

You either need to have your `success` handler look for cases where the HTTP request succeeded but the data says "error", or (better) have the PHP script use `http_response_code()` to change the HTTP status from 200 to something like 400 or 500 that will indicate an error.

Comment: that is exactly what I am trying to get in my php. To return a 500 status. So I have to use http_response_code, good to know! Thanks :)

Comment: I tried to apply your solution to my code (see edited code) but it always return 200. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code, use [http_response_code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) function to set HTTP status code to whatever you dream of.